# How to highlight word in livecode

Tags: livecode

How to highlight a word in green colour if it occurred in two times and if it occurred in three times then it should highlight in red colour if ti is occurred more than three then it should highlight with the colour orange. Is it possible. I am using the following code how i change my code

```
on mouseUp

   put the field "f1" into sss
      repeat for each word ass in sss
         if ass contains  shalu then
            --put tmp into 0
            add 1 to tmp
            --answer "answer found"

         end if

      end repeat

      answer tmp
      if tmp >2 then
         answer "more than two"
      else
         answer"only two times"
         hilight "shalu"
         end if
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 1):

in the code that I share below. Replace "work" with the word you want to search for and field 1 with a valid reference to your field

```
on mouseUp pButtonNumber
   local tText, tLine = 0, tNewValue = 1, tOff = 0, tNumChars, tWord, tCount = 0, tField, tResult, tColor
   
   put the long id of field 1 into tField
   put "work" into tWord
   
   put the text of tField into tText
   put the length of tWord into tNumChars
   
   repeat while tNewValue <> 0
      put offset(tWord, tText, tOff ) into tNewValue
      
      if tNewValue is 0 then exit repeat     -- all done!
      
      add 1 to tCount
      put (tOff  +tNewValue ), (tOff  +tNewValue + tNumChars ) & cr after tResult
      
      add tNumChars to tNewValue
      add tNewValue to tOff
   end repeat
   
   
   switch tCount
      case 1
         put "black" into tColor
         break
         
      case 2
         put "green" into tColor
         break
         
      case 3
         put "red" into tColor
         break
         
      default
         put "orange" into tColor
   end switch
   
   repeat for each line tline in tResult
      set the textColor of char (the item 1 of tline) to  (the item 2 of tline) of tField to tColor
   end repeat
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 0):

To hilite a word without selecting it, use the backColor property:

```
set the backColor of char 23 to 27 of fld 1 to green
```